# How to add a new element to array in arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I added 2 elements to my array in JavaScript and HTML,I want to add a copy to clipboard button as a new element to each array,but I am struggling to do this due to the complicated codes.
here is my code

```js
var currImage = 0;
window.onload = () => {
    const factsArr = [
 { image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7aD5tv1ogNBtDhDi/giphy.gif', source:"<a href='http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2010/03/100315-half-male-half-female-chickens/' style='text-decoration:none;color:#FFFFFF;' target='_blank'>know more</a>",},
 { image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/1nkUav308CBws/giphy.gif',      source:"<a href='http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/most-expensive-pizza' style='text-decoration:none;color:#FFFFFF;'target='_blank'>know more</a>"},
  ]:
  const swtch = () => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('image')[0].setAttribute('src', factsArr[currImage].image);
    document.getElementsByClassName('source')[0].innerHTML=factsArr[currImage].source;
 document.getElementById('copyToClipboard').innerHTML=copyToClipboard(element).copyToClipboard
    currImage++;
    if (currImage == factsArr.length)
        currImage = 0;
    console.log(currImage);
};
document.getElementsByClassName('generate-btn')[0].addEventListener('click', swtch);
document.getElementsByClassName('source')[0].addEventListener('click', swtch);
}
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="generate-btn">Amazing Fact Button</button>
<div class="source"></div>
<img class="image" />
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('element')">Copy Link</button>
```

Comment: You have some errors 1. document.getElementsById('copyToClipboard').innerHTML=copyToClipboard(element).copyToClipboard - element is not defined. 2. document.getElementsById('copyToClipboard').innerHTM - it should be document.getElementById('copyToClipboard').innerHTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var currImage = 0;
window.onload = () => {
    const factsArr = [
  { image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7aD5tv1ogNBtDhDi/giphy.gif', source:"<a href='http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2010/03/100315-half-male-half-female-chickens/' style='text-decoration:none;color:#FFFFFF;' target='_blank'>know more</a>",},
  { image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/1nkUav308CBws/giphy.gif',      source:"<a href='http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/most-expensive-pizza' style='text-decoration:none;color:#FFFFFF;'target='_blank'>know more</a>"},
  ];
  const swtch = () => {
    $('.image').attr('src', factsArr[currImage].image);
    $('.source').html(factsArr[currImage].source);
    $('.copyToClipboard').data('test',factsArr[currImage].image);
    $('.test').css('display', 'block');
    currImage++;
    if (currImage == factsArr.length)
        currImage = 0;
    console.log(currImage);
};
$('.generate-btn').on('click', swtch);
$('.source').on('click', swtch);
}
function copyToClipboard() {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($('.copyToClipboard').data('test')).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="generate-btn">Amazing Fact Button</button>
<div  class="test" style="display:none;">
<div class="source"></div>
<img class="image" />
<button class="copyToClipboard" onclick="copyToClipboard()">Copy Link</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Not exactly,I wanted the copy to clipboard to appear when Clicking "amazing fact button" and that the href changes to ach gif (so i can copy gif link)

Comment: Oh and I didnt vote negative that is probably someone else

Comment: It appears have you mention that in your question?

Comment: @TalalKhraisat if this update is helpful please accept this for others to refer.

Comment: sure but where can I edit the link that will be copied? I cant find it on the code

Comment: once you click on copy button it copies link to clipboard you can paste it from there.
just press CTRL+V(paste) on some editor you will see link pasted

Comment: No,what i meant was how can change or edit the link to each gif that will be copied?do I edit it from array image element??